# How to configure CI Bamboo plan to run tests in different environments?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

We have 2 development projects (for back-end and front-end) with separated Bamboo plans. And we have special test plan with functional tests. How to configure test project for running in different environment? (like develop/staging/live)

Or we need to create additional build plan for each environment?Any ideas? 
In test project I have config file with environment settings like

```
<add key="swdRemoteUrl" value="http://staging.web.com:4444/wd/hub"/>
<add key="swdBrowserType" value="Chrome"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using deployment projects?
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/deployment-projects-338363438.html

1. Build your artifacts with 3 settings
2. Deploy to each environment with suitable setting and test!

Comment: Should I make a deployment project from project with test, do you mean it? Or do you mean to create artifacts from product projects (which contain back end and frontend parts of our website)?

Comment: If you want to do these tests as a part of deployment pipeline, I think making a deployment project is good. If you want to do these tests as daily routine (like cron jobs), I think making some build projects(for develop/staging/live, etc) is good.